# Validate xml against xsd using c++

Tags: c++, windows, xml, linux

I am very new to XML and c++.

I want to validate XML against XSD using C++ API. Can any one give me some tutorial links or sample programs? I don't want to do this using MSXML as it works in Windows and Visual Studio.

I tried to use Xerces and libXML but I have failed. Now I am trying using tinyXML.

Please help me to validate XML against XML schema using c++ (not VC++, should work in cross platform).

Comment: What went wrong with `libxml2` ? I was able to build a C++ wrapper around it pretty easily.

Comment: @ereOn, were you able to validate against an XML Schema (.xsd) file with `libxml2`? I thought it only supported validation against DTD files

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [libsystools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libsystools/). It's an open-source, multi-platform, x86/x64 C++ library that includes XML (and XML schemas, aka. XSD) support.

It is based on `libxml2` but this is hidden.

It also handles a lot of stuff you probably don't want (sockets, openssl, xmlsec) so you might extract the XML classes and use them in your project instead. (Your software will have to be open-source though).

I you want to do so, I suggest you get the last sources using SVN (take the revision 315) and look at the files starting with `xml`.

*Note: The current 2.0 release **doesn't** have XSD validation support. The next release will be in months, so there is no other way but getting the source from the SVN repository. But that's no big deal.*

Comment: As per the writing of this comment, it appears that `libsystools` has been abandoned in 2013.